# Is it possible to use schema methods in mongoose aggregate return value?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a special situation and I use aggregate. But I could not use the schema methods in the return value of the aggregate.
Is there a way to solve this problem?

example source:

server:

```
itemSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    seller: ObjectId,
    category: String,
    price: Number,
    ....
});
itemSchema.methods = {
    getPriceToString(){
        return this.price.toString()
    }
    ...
}

let delay = 1000*60*60*24*30*5;
let item = yield item.aggregate({
{
    {
        $project:
        {
            "_id": 1,
            ...
            "created_at" : {
                $cond: { 
                    if: { ... }, 
                    then: {$subtract:["$created_at",delay]},
                    else: "$created_at" }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            "from": 'users',
            "localField": 'seller',
            "foreignField": '_id',
            "as": 'seller'
        },
    },
    {
        $sort:
        {
            'created_at' : -1
        }
    },
    {
        $limit: 40
    }
]).exec();
res.send({item:item});
```

front:

```
...
a(...)=item.seller.username
...
h2=item.getPriceToString()
```

error:

item.getPriceToString is not a function

Comment: Output of `.aggregate()` is the same as adding `.lean()` in that the output is simply "plain JavaScript Objects" and does not have access to any defined schema or methods. That said, provided you have a model definition that meets the same "shape" requirements that the output provides, then there is nothing wrong with feeding that plain object output to an instance constructor and returning mongoose documents. But you must do that manually. Aggregations "typically" change the shape. So the schema no longer applies by design.